# Facebook OAuth with Firebase and Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have a react-native app created with Expo and m Firebase as the backend.

I have already done the Facebook login which gives me the facebook token

Now that I have gotten the facebook token, I am trying to integrate my app to use Firebase (so that i have the Firebase userid) which I am encountering difficulties

I searched online and only found the code for Google Oauth

```
googleAuthenticate = (idToken, accessToken) => {
      const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);
      return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
};
```

Anyone can share how they integrate facebook oauth with firebase together with Expo? Thanks

Comment: Hey Hendry, please reward my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code for auth from Facebook and google.

**Facebook Code:**

```
LoginManager
        .logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
        .then((result) => {
            if (!result.isCancelled) {
                console.log(`Login success with permissions: ${result.grantedPermissions.toString()}`)
                // get the access token
                return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                // create a new firebase credential with the token
                const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken)
                // login with credential
                return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
            }
        })
        .then((currentUser) => {
            if (currentUser) {
                //Here is user profile 
            }
        }
```

**Google Code:**

```
 GoogleSignin.configure()
        .then(() => {
            GoogleSignin.signIn()
                .then((data) => {
                    // create a new firebase credential with the token
                    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.idToken, data.accessToken)

                    // login with credential
                    return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)

                })
                .then((currentUser) => {
                   //Here is user profile
                }
```

**And this is simple login code:**

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password)
                            .then((user) => {
                               //Here is user profile after login
                            }
```

Thanks and let me know if need more!!

Comment: Sorry. I'm not so experienced with stackoverflow. I tot I upvote yesterday?

Comment: please accept my answer, from ticking on left side of my answer